# Webpack and jQuery inline script

Tags: jquery, webpack

I've add jQuery on global in my Webpack config. But if i use jQuery on inline script, jQuery is not defined :

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
  })
]
```

Anyone have any idea ? How i can define jQuery on global with Webpack ?

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Various options to deal with "broken modules" are covered in the [shimming](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/) user guide of webpack.

Inline scripts might not work very well with webpack. The [script-loader](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/#script-loader) could do the trick.